# Ruby Quiz for Python

Tags: python

Is there a blog/forum/listserv that is equivalent to RubyQuiz.com for the Python language?

Answer (score 2):

How about the [Python Challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/)?

It isn't a weekly challenge, more a fixed set of challenges of increasing difficulty but it is fun and educational none-the-less.  A great way to get to know python and have fun solving puzzles.  Try to do them yourself without cheating to get the most out of it!

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, why not just do the rubyquiz examples in python. Those exercises as well as others aren't tied to a language - you're just as well off just doing projecteuler problems in python rather than searching for python-specific puzzles. A puzzle is a puzzle a language is just a tool to solve it.

Comment: Probably he'd like to see the available solutions as well.

Comment: plenty of people post their solutions in python on projecteuler and such

Comment: Thanks. I would've liked to have seen the available solutions but I find Project Euler interesting too.